# Evaluating improper definite integrals

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I have been attempting to solve the following integral as part of a solid state physics problem:

$$\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x^2e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}\,dx$$

Can someone please explain how this can be evaluated?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: First show the problem in $0$ can be erased ($f(0)$  exists by continuity $e^x-1=x+o(x)$). Then substitute $u=e^x$ you will get dilog.

Comment: extremely close to your earlier question an hour ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3714227/evaluating-an-improper-definite-integral

Comment: @amWhy: the earlier question was asked without the square in the denominator. The OP changed the denominator, then restored it due to complaints in comments that he restore it to its original state and pose the altered question elsewhere. Then, it was changed again to the square in the denominator, but not by the OP, so perhaps he did not know it was the same. In fact, the edit to the square in the denominator in the other question was after your comment above.

Comment: @robjohn  I do not believe I called this question a duplicate.   Did you have a point to make in your comment, like chastising me?  If you're so offended, then go back to post with the typo, to allow the fastest guns in the west there to save face.

Comment: No, just explaining why the questions looked so similar.

Answer (score -2):

According to Maple the answer is $$-2\,{\it dilog} \left( {{\rm e}^{2}} \right) -4\,{\frac {{{\rm e}^{2}}
}{{{\rm e}^{2}}-1}}.$$
AFAIK this can't be simplified to anything more elementary. Numerically the value is approximately $1.801718567$.